# Reproducibility issue of an openMP output

Tags: c, unix, openmp

I am going through openMP tutorials and as I progressed, I have written an openMP version of a code that calculates PI by using an integral.

I have written a serial version so I know the serial counterpart is ok. Once the openMP version completed, I noticed that everytime I run it, it gives me a different answer. If I do several runs, I can see that the outputs is broadly around the right number but still, I didn't expect several openMP run give different answers.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<omp.h>

void main()

{ int nb=200,i,blob;



 float summ=0,dx,argg;
 dx=1./nb;

 printf("\n dx------------: %f \n",dx);


 omp_set_num_threads(nb);
 #pragma omp parallel
 {

 blob=omp_get_num_threads();

 printf("\n we have now %d number of threads...\n",blob);

 int ID=omp_get_thread_num();
 i=ID;
 printf("\n i is now: %d \n",i);

 argg=(4./(1.+i*dx*i*dx))*dx;
 summ=summ+argg;
 printf("\t\t and summ is %f \n",summ);
 }


 printf("\ntotal summ after loop: %f\n",summ);

 }
```

I compile this code on a RedHat using gcc -f mycode.c -fopenmp and when I run it, say 3 times, I get:

3.117

3.113

3.051

Could anyone help to understand why I get different results? Am I doing something wrong? The parallelism just splic the integration interval, but as the rectangles are calculated , it should be the same when they get summed up at the end, no?

the serial version gives me 3.13

(the fact I don't get 3.14 is normal because I used a very coarse sampling of the integral with just 200 divisions between 0 and 1)

I have tried also to add a barrier, but I still get different answers, although closer to the serial-version, still with a spread in values and not identical...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem lies in declaring `int i` and `float argg` outside the parallel loop.

What's happening is that all your 200 threads are overwriting `i` and `argg`, so sometimes the `argg` of a thread is overwritten by `argg` from another thread, resulting in the unpredictable error that you observe.

Here is a working code that always prints the same value (up to 6 decimals or so):

```
void main()
{
    int nb = 200, blob;
    float summ = 0, dx;// , argg;
    dx = 1. / nb;

    printf("\n dx------------: %f \n", dx);

    omp_set_num_threads(nb);
#pragma omp parallel
    {

        blob = omp_get_num_threads();

        printf("\n we have now %d number of threads...\n", blob);

        int i = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("\n i is now: %d \n", i);

        float argg = (4. / (1. + i * dx*i*dx))*dx;
        summ = summ + argg;
        printf("\t\t and summ is %f \n", summ);
    }

    printf("\ntotal summ after loop: %f\n", summ);
}
```

However, changing the last line to %.9f reveals that it's not in fact the exact same float number. This is due to numerical errors in floating point additions. a+b+c does not guarantee the same result as a+c+b. You can try this in below example:

First add `float* arr = new float[nb];` **before** the parallel loop AND `arr[i] = argg;` **within** the parallel loop, after `argg` is defined, of course. Then add the following **after** the parallel loop:

```
float testSum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++)
    testSum += arr[i];
printf("random sum: %.9f\n", testSum);

std::sort(arr, arr + nb);
testSum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++)
    testSum += arr[i];
printf("sorted sum: %.9f\n", testSum);

testSum = 0;
for (int i = nb-1; i >= 0; i--)
    testSum += arr[i];
printf("reversed sum: %.9f\n", testSum);
```

Most likely, the sorted sum and reversed sum are slightly different, even though they are composed by adding up the exact same 200 numbers.

Another thing you might want to note is that you're very unlikely to find a processor that can actually run 200 threads in parallel. Most common processors can handle 4 to 32 threads, while specialised server processors can go up to 112 threads with the $15k Xeon Platinum 9282.

As such, we usually do the following:

We remove `omp_set_num_threads(nb);` to use the recommended number of threads

We remove `int i = omp_get_thread_num();` to use `int i` from for loop

We rewrite the loop as a for loop:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++)
    {...}
```

The result should be identical, but you're now only using as many threads as available on the actual hardware. This reduces context switching between threads and should improve time-performance of your code.

Comment: Hi Leighton many thanks you were right, your suggestion solved the problem. Thanks again !

Comment: Hi @leighton-ritchie I have an additional question with respect to the code above. First of all I do confirm that wherever I do ./a.out (that is, just a simple interactive run) the correction you provided do indeed yield the same number. But I did an experiment and instead of just doing./a.out, I did ./a.out > output.txt, then tail -10 output.txt. I then notice that the printed final value ("total summ after loop") can actually differ from time to time. Do you know if somehow the redirection to a file can impair the process? Should I then write into a file while inside  the code?

Comment: There is no reason for piped output to be different.
How many decimal places does it "differ from time to time"? I assume it's beyond the 6th decimal place. I also assume that using "total summ after loop" means you did not sort it. If so, this subjects your program to (possible) numerical errors, as mentioned after the first code block in my answer. Probably, running the interactive program more times would reveal that it was not, in fact, exactly the same float. You can see more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property#Nonassociativity_of_floating_point_calculation)

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from variables  `summ`, `argg` and `i`. They belong to the global sequential scope and cannot be modified without precautions. You will have races between threads and this may result in an unexpected values in these var. Races are completely undeterministic and that explains the different results that you get. You may as well get the correct result or any incorrect result depending on the temporal occurrences of reads and writes to these vars.

The proper way to deal with this  problem :

- for variable `argg` and `i`: they are declared in the global scope, but they are used to perform temporay computation in the threads. You should : either declare them in the parallel domain to make them thread private, or add `private(argg,i)` in the omp directive. Note hat there also a potential problem for `blob`, but its value is identical in all threads and this should not modify the behavior of the program.
- for variable `summ` the situation is different. This is *really* a global variable that accumulates some values from the threads. It must remain global, but you must add the `atomic` openmp directive when modifying it. The complete read-modify-write operation on the variable will become unbreakable and this will ensure a race free modification.

Here is a modified version of your code that give coherent result (but floats are not associative and the last decimal may change).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<omp.h>

void main()

{
  int nb=200,i,blob;
  float summ=0,dx,argg;
  dx=1./nb;

  printf("\n dx------------: %f \n",dx);

  omp_set_num_threads(nb);
# pragma omp parallel private(argg,i)
  {
    blob=omp_get_num_threads();

    printf("\n we have now %d number of threads...\n",blob);

    int ID=omp_get_thread_num();
    i=ID;
    printf("\n i is now: %d \n",i);

    argg=(4./(1.+i*dx*i*dx))*dx;
    #pragma omp atomic
    summ=summ+argg;

    printf("\t\t and summ is %f \n",summ);
  }

  printf("\ntotal summ after loop: %f\n",summ);

}
```

As already noted, this is not the best way to use threads. Creating and synchronizing threads is expensive and it is rarely required to have more threads that the number of cores.

Comment: Hello @alain-merigot ,many thanks for having taken the time to comprehensively explain the issue. I do have a question with respect to the code you wrote: when I run it, the pragma atomic seems to yield an error. I get:                                       **error: invalid operator for ‘#pragma omp atomic’ before ‘=’ token'**

Comment: I think the problem comes from the space before `#pragma` . I have no problem compiling it with gcc, and I prefer to indent in order to show code logic, but C standard say that these directives should start at column 0 of a line and other compilers may be stricter. Try removing all space in order to start line with `'#'` and it should work.

Comment: Ok so just to share the solution I have found to bypass the problem, I replaced summ=summ+argg by summ+=argg and it stopped giving the error, and the code with the modification you shared then works properly. While browsing, I did find out that some versions (of what? gcc? OS? openMP? not explained) requires specifically a condensed syntax for the incrementation that follows a #pragma omp critical. (PS: please upvote the question if you find it useful for the community)

Comment: Right. While both forms are equivalent, some compilers require that the read-modify-write operation appears explicitly.